# How to select the last row that matches a select where COL in (a,b,c)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a SQL query (MySql) that returns the last row from the "in" clause based on the order of the values in the IN(a,b,c). To simplify the problem, here is a sample table, and the results I need from the query.

```
For the Table PEOPLE, with values
LAST_NAME    FIRST_NAME
.....
Smith        Mike    
Smith        Betty
Smith        Jane
Jones        Mike
Jones        Sally
....
```

I need a query with like

```
SELECT * 
FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Mike' AND LAST_NAME IN ('Smith','Jones')
```

to return Mike Jones, and a query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Mike' AND LAST_NAME IN ('Jones','Smith')
```

to return Mike Smith

Basically the `WHERE LAST_NAME IN (....)` serves an "over-ride" function where the members of the list can over-ride values in the result set based on the order from the members of the `IN (...)` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)  in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Mike' 
      AND LAST_NAME IN ('Smith','Jones') 
ORDER BY FIELD(LAST_NAME, 'Smith', 'Jones') DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Just repeat string literal values of `IN`, using the same order, inside `FIELD`.

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I thought, and the LIMIT 1 always returns the last match? This makes me wonder. I was going to do a SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME WHERE LAST_NAME IN (list) and then for each FIRST_NAME in that result set do the SELECT statement you have above.  is there an easy way to combine those two statements into a single statement?

Comment: @MikeStorey `LIMIT 1` returns the top level record, i.e. the one having the smallest `FIELD` value, i.e. the one that is the leftmost.

Comment: I need to return the LAST record, is there a way to do that without having to reverse the member list.... i.e. LIMIT -1 or something?

Comment: @MikeStorey Just use `DESC`

Comment: I found my answer to that question.... SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Mike' AND LAST_NAME IN ('Smith','Jones') ORDER BY FIELD(LAST_NAME, 'Smith','Jones') DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

giogios' solution is good. Without using limit this should work too, so if you have multiple Mike Jones or Mike Smith, you get all the results for those mike Jones and Mike Smith will appear. It is unlikely but not impossible if your database doesn't use any of these fields as primary-keys.

```
select * From emp_master 
where FIRST_NAME = 'Mike'
    And (LAST_NAME = 
          case LAST_NAME 
               when 'jones'    then 'jones' 
               when 'Smith' then 'Smith'
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit & try this - should give you required output

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_Name ORDER BY unique_column DESC
```